# Copying part of string into a new string character by character in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

Hi I have a string that was initialized as:

```
char *line = malloc(100);
```

Then I used the `fgets` function to read a line from a file into `line`

From there i made another string that was initialized as

```
char *word = malloc(100);
```

My goal is to read the first word of `line` character by character and insert those characters into `word`, up until there is a space in `line`.

This is what I have tried.

```
while(*line != 32){
        *line = *word;
        line++;
        word++;
    }

*word = '\0';
printf("%s\n", word);
```

For some reason when I print the value of `word` afterwards, only blank spaces are being printed. Meaning that I was unsuccessful. However, I can print `*line` character by character and have the expected value. Why?

Comment: Think more about what `line++` and `word++` are really doing... And think about this: If you have e.g. `int a = 10; x++; printf("%d\n", a);`, would you be surprised if the printed value was `10` or `11`?

Comment: Also there is a way to *not* throw magic numbers like `32` around: use `' '` instead.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala 32 is the ascii value

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it works for printing every character one by one for `line`

Comment: @User9123 Using `' '` instead of `32` is both more readable and more portable

Comment: @klutt i use the ascii values in more spots throughout my entire code so it keeps it more consistent

Comment: @User9123 so you're writing consistently bad code. Well, I guess consistency is good.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala not really, for parts of my code i am searching for carraige returns, horizontal tabs etc... much easier to do `if(*line <= 31)` than whatever you suggested

Comment: @User9123 Consistency is not always a good thing. And besides, there are escape sequences for carriage returns and tabs too. Also, you are not consistent. In the code you posted you're using `'\0'` instead of `0`. ;)

Comment: Yes, but once you do e.g. `word++` you loose the original pointer stored in `word`. You're doing `word = word + 1` The pointer returned by `malloc` is lost. Think more about the example with the integer in my first comment.

Comment: @klutt nope if i want to search frrom ascii value 0 to 31, there is not a more efficient way... and \0 is for the end of the string not for searching

Comment: @User9123 Sure, but that's not what you were doing here. But do as you like.

Comment: @klutt yes but that is what I am doing in other parts of my code... like I said consistency

Comment: @User9123 Nope. I'm just trying to give you advice. If I we were working on the same code base and I was senior over you, I would never accept such code to enter the upstream. And I know that many others would reason the same. If you want to interpret that as "hating", well, I guess there's nothing I can do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you are changing the value of `line` instead of `word`. Just a quick eye test shows me you should probably update your code to `*word = *line;`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're modifying both `line` and `word`. When you do `word++` you are moving the pointer one character forward, so in the end what you end up doing is only printing the last character of `word`, which is `\0` as you just assigned it.

To do this correctly the simplest way is to use auxiliary variables:

```
char *l, *w;
l = line;
w = word;

while(*l != ' ' && *l != '\0') {
    *w = *l;
    l++;
    w++;
}

*w = '\0';
printf("%s\n", word);
```

The added check for `*l != '\0'` is to make sure you don't read past the end of `line` in case there no space character is found.

Another option would be to use an auxiliary index variable accessing the two strings like arrays, instead of using other pointers:

```
size_t i;

for (i = 0; line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    word[i] = line[i];
}

word[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", word);
```